# Connecting Python to MSSQL using Pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I'm having an issue connecting a live system to a new MSSQL database instance through Pymssql. I've no problem connecting to the previous old instance, but when I change the connection string to the new one and reload my code in apache I get the following authentication error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymssql.OperationalError) (18456, "Login failed for user '*****'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (*********************)\n")
```

The problem is, the exact same connection (with the same login details) works fine locally. I can login and access the new database instance  through Pymssql with no issues. I'm assuming my FreeTD's are up to date as well seeing as I can connect fine to the old instance. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as to why the new connection won't work for the live system.

Comment: I had similar issues, take a look at this and see if any of it helps. If not, I have no idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035924/connecting-to-local-sql-server-instance

Comment: Great, will give it a whizz!

Answer (score 7):

Ok so the issue was that pymssql has an upper password limit of 30 characters. My new instance connection password exceeded this. Just in case anybody has the same problem.